# CPU consumption of my process

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I would like to use Performance Monitor to check the CPU consumption of my process.
Right now I am working on a MultiCore machine.

If I have a look at my process in TASK MANAGER I see that my process consumes 20% of CPU.
If I start performance monitor, I select Process->->% Processor Time
I see values peaking up and over 100%.
Do you know why and how to get the real measure?

I also looked at the CPU consumption for all of my 4 cores, but I don't know exactly how to attribute consumption to my process.

If you can suggest a link or url about how to read CPU usage I would really appreciate!
Thanks a lot!
AFG

Answer (score 1):

Try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Sysinternals.  Very useful.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2007/02/02/system-diagnostics-performancecounter-and-processor-time-on-multi-core-or-multi-cpu.aspx) explains what you are seeing.

Basically Task Manager averages the cores together, and Performance Monitor sums up the the `Process`'s time on each core.  So, `% Processor Time` on a system with 4 cores could go up to 400.  `N * 100 = MaxValue;` Where N is the number of cores/processors in the system.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it! The thing is that I would like to stick for now on PerformanceMonitor since because on my C# app I can add my counters...
Thanks anyway!
Mn